# How do I dynamically create an array of strings using scanf in C

Tags: c

So I have been searching through stack overflow for a little over an hour and I don't understand why this function is giving me a segmentation error. I want to create a string array, scan strings in through scanf, dynamically change the size of each string and return the string array. Can anyone help? Thank you.

```
char** readScores(int* count) {
    int c = 0;
    char** arr =(char**)malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));
    char* in;
    while(scanf("%s", in) != EOF) {
        arr[c] = (char*)malloc(strlen(in)+1);
        strcpy(arr[c], in);
    }
    *count = c;
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Did you read your book? Consult and study the documentation for the features you've used? Step through the program with your debugger? Just searching SO for an hour isn't going to cut it as far as debugging goes.

Comment: You have to allocate memory for `in` before `scanf`

Comment: I would do this but my professor didn't provide us a book and I am using emacs on a linux system without a debugger.

Comment: Then you need to get a book, and you need to install a debugger.

Comment: @fas thank you I was going crazy!

Comment: @fas Please avoid answering in the comments section.

Comment: @KyleW Your prof might be teaching you a kind lesson: if your development tools are inadequate, get or make better ones.  There is no humanist, economic, or productive argument to having a developer work with inadequate tools; especially since most are actually free ( plus cost of download).

Comment: @fas, minor nitpick: You don't have to allocate memory for `in`. By virtue of being a variable. `in` already has memory. Enough of it to store a pointer. What you *do* have to do is to arrange for `in` to point to something meaningful.

Comment: @HAL9000 no, the unadorned `char *` points at nothing; the program has to make it point at some valid lump of memory which it then permits scanf to write into.  As is, this is the exact sort of code that exploit writers look for.

Comment: @mevets, you are right, `in` points to nowhere, or somewhere undefined. But i never claimed `in` had memory for a string. What I nitpicked was the terminology used by @fas. I use that terminology myself when talking to people that understands pointers. But for Stackoverflow readers that is not always the case. A lot of beginners believe memory allocated with `malloc` "belongs to", or "is part of" the pointer variable. A more precise way to express the answer would be to say: "allocate memory for `scanf` to store the string, and have `in` point to that memory".

Answer (score 1):

```
char* in;
while(scanf("%s", in) != EOF) {
```

This tells the computer to read from *standard input* into the `char` buffer that `in` points to.

Which does not exist, because `in` is not initialised to anything (let alone a valid buffer).

Answer (score 0):

I would not use scanf only fgets.

You need to allocate memory dor the `arr` and for every line referenced by elements of `arr`

```
char** readScores(size_t *count) {
    size_t lines = 0;
    char** arr = NULL, **tmp;
    char* in = malloc(MAXLINE), *result;
    size_t len;

    if(in)
    {
        do{
            result = fgets(in, MAXLINE, stdin);           
            if(result)
            {
                len = strlen(in);
                tmp = realloc(arr, sizeof(*tmp) * (lines + 1));
                if(tmp)
                {
                    arr = tmp;
                    len = strlen(in);
                    arr[lines] = malloc(len + (len == 0));
                    if(arr[lines])
                    {
                        if(len) memcpy(arr[lines], in, len - 1);
                        arr[lines++][len] = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // error handling     
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // error handling 
                }
            }
        }while(result);
        free(in);
    }
    *count = lines;
    return arr;
}
```